# Can I create a view from another view and then drop temporary

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a temporary view like :

```
CREATE VIEW temp_view AS SELECT .....
```

Then by calling some functions to define a name I want create my normal view as :

```
--- my main_viewYYYYMMDD will have the contents of temp_view
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format( 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.%I '
                ' AS SELECT * FROM schema.temp_view', getViewName()  ) ;
END ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

and then `DROP VIEW temp_view ;` fails because there are dependent views.

Would `CREATE TEMP VIEW temp_view ...` fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `VIEW` from it's definition using `pg_get_viewdef`

```
create or replace view temp_view as select * from employees;
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format( 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.%I '
                ' AS %s ' , 'yourviewname' ,pg_get_viewdef('temp_view', true)) ;
                DROP VIEW temp_view;
END ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

You may also have `temp_view` created as a  Temporary view. Temporary views are automatically dropped at the end of the current session. But, it's definition will be visible until the end of the session. You need not include the `drop view` in your `do` block for that scenario in case you aren't performing anything else on it till the end of the session.

Comment: I'll give it a try. If I create it as a temp view - does it create dependents though? Can it be dropped at the end of current session?

Comment: @ghostrider : No, a View  created on a temporary view will also be a Temporary View. Check edits.